# Raspberry Pi with nginx in docker connected to a fritz.box is not available from the internet

Tags: docker, nginx, raspberry-pi, webserver

I am trying to implement a small webserver on a raspberry pi which is connected to my fritz.box.
I already setup docker on my raspberry pi with nginx and if I call the internal ip of my raspberry pi with the port 8080 I can receive my "Hello-World" php site.
So far so good...
Now I installed the nginx proxy manager and this is reachable on port 80. So If I just call my internal ip of my raspberry pi I see a page of the nginx proxy manager.
So this seems to be working too.

Now I want that this is also accessible from external requests. I created a domain with no-ip.com and inserted the credentials in the backend of my fritz.box under dyndns. Also I created the port approval for my raspberry pi for the port 80 and 443.

So I thought if I did it like this and call my no-ip.com domain it will be directed to my fritz.box port 80 which is directing to the nginx proxy manager site.

But I only receive a Connection Timeout when calling the site...

Did I miss something or did I something wrong?

**Update:**
I realized that in my fritz.box opened the Ports 80 and 443 for IPv6 and for IPv4 it was 1155 and 1157.
So if I run my no-ip.com domain with port 1155 I can reach the nginx proxy manager.
I tried to implement the port 80 redirect at no-ip.com like **@VonC** mentioned. But I only can create on host and if I create only the port 80 redirect then the domain leads me to a 404 page which I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Check first if your ISP or routeur would not block port 80 ingress.

After all, the [no-ip.com documentation](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/port-80-redirect/) itself does mention:

> Port 80 is the default port for HTTP (Hyper Text Transfer Protocol). Most servers and system across the globe use Port 80.
> **It is very common for Internet Service Providers (ISP) to block all data to this port**.
> You can resolve this by redirecting traffic to a different port using our `Port 80 Redirect service`.

Comment: Thank that gets me further - but unfortunately this leads me to a 404 page (s. my update)

Comment: @Michael The idea would be to redirect to your existing 8080 port. Meaning a port actively listened to by your nginx through Docker.

Comment: ok, but how can I do that?

Comment: @Michael If you can access to your raspberry pi only through the port 1155, that means your docker image must run with a port mapping 1155:8080.